# Python Pandas Errno 13 while saving dataframe to xlsx

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am slowly loosing my mind. I'm trying to save pandas dataframe to xlsx.

```
save_path = self.SAVE_L['text']+ f"\df_{part}_.xlsx"
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter(save_path , engine='xlsxwriter',date_format='DD/MM/YYYY',datetime_format='DD/MM/YYYY')
df.to_excel(writer , index=False, sheet_name='df', engine='xlsxwriter') 
writer.save()
```

However, for bigger df (but still in range of excel files - around 550 000 lines) I'm getting this error:

```
//NETWORK_DISK/save_path\df_part1_.xlsx
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "PATH to script/Prog 0.31.py", line 460, in Process
    scr_t=self.scr_list)
  File "PATH to script/Prog 0.31.py", line 829, in script_PROC
    writer.save()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 1952, in save
    return self.book.close()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\workbook.py", line 310, in close
    self._store_workbook()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\workbook.py", line 636, in _store_workbook
    xlsx_file.write(os_filename, xml_filename)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\zipfile.py", line 1746, in write
    with open(filename, "rb") as src, self.open(zinfo, 'w') as dest:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Pandriej\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpfi53pba3'
```

I can save it to .csv without any problem. I also can divide it into smaller chunks and save them individually. The problem is I need the entire output to be saved as xlsx.

Is there any way I can fix this? Make Pandas actually save the file?

Comment: By any chance is there an open file with the same name as `save_path`?

Comment: No. I even create new save folder every time I run the script.

Comment: The save folder is nowewhere near AppData. This `C:\\Users\\Pandriej\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpfi53pba3` path is nothing that I have chosen.

Comment: I tried to do something with \ and / but it works for smaller df as is. It seems that pandas is making a temp file in AppData that is too big(?)